# Syntax error in trigger statement

Tags: mysql, sql

When my `users_reputation` points table gets updated (insert), I want to take a new count (SUM) of this user's points and update a `total_rep` column in the `users` table.

This is what I came up with but keep getting syntax errors. I would greatly appreciate if somebody could point out my mistakes.

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_rep_points AFTER INSERT ON users_reputation
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE new_total INT(10);
SELECT SUM(rep_points) INTO new_total FROM users_reputation
WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;
UPDATE users SET rep_total = new_total WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;
END
```

These are my table examples for reference:

**USERS:**

```
  user_id    |  first_name    |  total_rep
-------------+----------------+--------------
  10001      |  Jim           |  17
  10002      |  Bob           |  5
```

**USERS_REPUTATION:**

```
  user_id  |  rep_task                     |  rep_points  |  rep_date
-----------+-------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------
  10001    |  Commented on article         |  5           |  2012-11-12 08:40:32
  10001    |  Read an article              |  2           |  2012-06-12 12:32:01
  10001    |  Shared an article            |  10          |  2012-06-04 17:39:44
  10001    |  Read an article              |  2           |  2012-05-19 01:04:11
  10002    |  Commented on article         |  5           |  2012-06-17 09:34:21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a delimiter change at the beginning.

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_rep_points AFTER INSERT ON users_reputation
...
END

|
delimiter ;
```

The delimiter signals the DB engine the end of your statement. Normally it is `;`. But that would end the stored procedure at the first `;`. And its definition would be incomplete.

You can change the delimiter and add it to the end of your procedure. After that change the delimiter back to `;`

Comment: And my shared hosting account doesn't support 'Super User' MySQL privileges! So that was a waste of an hour! Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Jeez, I hate it when I spend hours on an issue, start to post a question, then the final "Questions that may already have your answer" points me to an answer.  Like here.  Thanks.